# vuejs - sync variables within the same file

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vuejs2

I have a vue (version 2.x) file where I have 3 fields - `input1 x input2 = result`

Now, when I change any one of them, the other two should be updated on the fly.
I tried using `watch` property but that leads to infinite loop because the watchers keep calling each other.

Is there any vue related helper which I am missing here? Any help would be appreciated.

Refer this for example code.

```
<template>
  <input v-model="input1"></input>
  <input v-model="input2"></input>
  <input v-model="conversionRate"></input>
</template>

<script>
export default {
  data() {
    input1: null,
    input2: null,
    conversionRate: null
  },
  watch: {
    input1() {
      this.input2 = this.input1 * this.conversionRate
    },
    input2() {
      this.input1 = this.input2 * this.conversionRate
    },
    conversionRate() {
      this.input2 = this.input1 * this.conversionRate
    }
  }
}
</script>
```

Comment: what it is supposed to do with `input1` and `input2` if we edit `result` ?

Comment: I am basically doing a currency conversion. input2 is the conversion rate here. So to answer your question, if you edit the result, keep input2 fixed and change input1.

Comment: If everything is bound properly and you're using v-model, the fields should update automatically anyway. P.s Show some code.

Comment: I think you'll have to use `@input` and `:value=` instead of `v-model` and use intermediate values to prevent this effect of infinite loop. (`currency1InputValue` -> `currency1`, `currency2InputValue` -> `currency2`, etc...)

Comment: Let me write the basic code and add it in the question itself @webnoob

Comment: Take a look at computed with setter and getter.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since all three models are dependent on each other it causes an infinite loop.

As per your requirement you can use [computed setter](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/computed.html#Computed-Setter).

### HTML

```
<div id="app">
  <input type="number" placeholder="amount" v-model="inputA"> X
  <input type="number" placeholder="rate" v-model="conversionRate"> =
  <input type="number" placeholder="total" v-model="total">
</div>
```

### SCRIPT

```
new Vue({
  el: "#app",
  data: {
    total: 0,
    conversionRate: 1
  },
  computed: {
    inputA: {
      get() {
        return this.total / this.conversionRate;
      },
      set(newVal) {
        this.total = newVal * this.conversionRate;
      }
    }
  }
});
```

Here is the [working fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/3gjkznq0/16/)

Comment: this works just fine. But when I use Math.round, the get(),set() and get() gets called and it does not work as expected. Suppose if I change the total, the get() is called, which changes the inputA value, which calls set(), which in turn changes the total value again. So the value which I type gets changed. Can you help me with this situation?

Comment: `inputA: {
      get() {
        return Math.round(this.total / this.conversionRate);
      },
      set(newVal) {
        this.total = Math.round(newVal * this.conversionRate);
      }
    }`

Answer (score 0):

Your watcher at `input2` is wrong which causes infinite loop (if the calulcation is based on float, you'd better to use Math.round), it should be:

```
input2: function (newVal) {
   this.input1 = newVal / this.conversionRate // not newVal*this.conversionRate
}
```

But @Vamsi Krishna should be an better solution.

**The demo:**

```js
app = new Vue({
  el: "#app",
  data: function () {
    return {
      input1: null,
      input2: null,
      conversionRate: 1
    }
  },
  watch: {
    input1: function (newVal) {
      this.input2 = newVal * this.conversionRate
    },
    input2: function (newVal) {
      this.input1 = newVal / this.conversionRate
    },
    conversionRate: function (newVal) {
      this.input2 = this.input1 * newVal
    }
  }
})
```

```html
<script src="https://unpkg.com/vue@2.5.16/dist/vue.js"></script>
<div id="app">
  <input v-model="input1">
  <input v-model="input2">
  <input v-model="conversionRate">
</div>
```